# How can I have 2 sliders for a form value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am sure this is possible but I have not been able to find an example or anything yet.

I have a search form on my site where users can search for other users bas on there age range, for example there is 2 dropdown list with age numbers like **16-35**.

Is there a way to have a horizontal line and have numbers accross it and 2 objects I can slide back and forth to a number?  I have seen it before but not in jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery UI library has just what you are looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Answer (score 0):

Another option is this jQuery extension, which will convert two select elements to a slider:

[`http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/`](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/)

If you are using specifically defined values rather than a continuous range, it may be a more suitable option.  It also provides the benefit of graceful degradation.